# Google places API "findplacefromtext" doesn't return a place accoring to the input

Tags: google-maps

The google places API "findplacefromtext" doesn't return the place according to the input, moreover is returning a place with the text nothing like the input.
As the example shows, the response have no similarity with the input.
Does anyone know why, or how to overcome this issue?

Request - input: **martin, Deutschland**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=martin,%20Deutschland&inputtype=textquery&fields=geometry,formatted_address&locationbias=point:50,10&key=<API-key>
```

Response - formatted address: **Proskauer Str. 29 Privatadresse, 10247 Berlin, Deutschland**

```
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Proskauer Str. 29 Privatadresse, 10247 Berlin, Deutschland",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.517325,
               "lng" : 13.4607768
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.51860572989272,
                  "lng" : 13.46209407989272
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.51590607010728,
                  "lng" : 13.45939442010728
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Regards

Comment: What do the other fields of the response have in them?  (the ones you didn't request in the response) I suspect you will find "martin" somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests), the `input` parameter

```
identifies the search target, such as a name, address, or phone number
```

In your case, the input query matches the **name** of the returned point of interest which is "*Dr. Martin Deutschland, Neurologische Überweisungspraxis*":

Request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=martin,%20Deutschland&inputtype=textquery&fields=name,place_id,geometry,formatted_address&locationbias=point:50,10&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Just add 'name' in the fields parameter.

Full response:

```
{
candidates: [
    {
        formatted_address: "Proskauer Str. 29 Privatadresse, 10247 Berlin, Deutschland",
        geometry: {
                location: {
                lat: 52.517325,
                lng: 13.4607768
            },
            viewport: {
                northeast: {
                    lat: 52.51860572989272,
                    lng: 13.46209407989272
                },
                southwest: {
                    lat: 52.51590607010728,
                    lng: 13.45939442010728
                }
            }
        },
        name: "Dr. Martin Deutschland, Neurologische Überweisungspraxis",
        place_id: "ChIJy0Ta3WBOqEcRUbGdPRF0QS4"
    }
],
status: "OK"
```

}

Note that the API takes into account several factors in searching for a certain query and given location. While location biasing is not strict, rather adds a bias to prefer results within the specified area, the best match or closely relevant feature will be returned based on those factors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved the mystery for me.
The proper API that I was looking for is the autocomplete.
web service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete
JS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete